# Create a datetime by faker laravel with format dd-mm-yyyy minute hour second, for example : 26/01/2022 20:52:23

Tags: php, laravel, faker

```
'from' => $this->faker->dateTime($max = 'now', $timezone = null),
'to' => $this->faker->dateTime($max = 'now', $timezone = null),
```

In my factory file, I use method dateTime for "from" and "to", but it create with format : yyyy-mm-dd. How can I create value for "from" with format dd-mm-yyyy minute hour second ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that Carbon is included natively in Laravel, however, if you wanted a native PHP solution, since the Faker dateTime function returns a DateTime object, you can use the `format()` function of the DateTime class, the documentation for which can be [found here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

The code for that might look like this:

```php
'from' => $this->faker->dateTime()->format('d-m-Y H:i:s'),
```

Comment: It work to me, but I meet an error Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '05-04-1972 19:03:11' for column 'from' at row 1 (SQL: insert into discounts (name, from, to, status, updated_at, created_at) values (Ms. Cassandra Raynor, 05-04-1972 19:03:11, 19-08-2014 03:56:37, 0, 2022-01-27 00:24:07, 2022-01-27 00:24:07)) –

Comment: It's have an error. I think because I defined wrong value for from column for it $table->dateTime('from', $precision =0); How can I fix this ? –

Comment: @DragonSayler that's a limitation of the DateTime format. You need to provide it with the DateTime string in a very specific format. See the [docs here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html). Within PHP, to get a format that will work, you need to use the formatter string of `Y-m-d H:i:s`. It should work after this.

Answer (score 4):

How about the following:

```php
'from' => \Carbon\Carbon::parse($this->faker->dateTime($max = 'now', $timezone = null))->format('d-m-Y H:i:s'),
```

You can replace `-` in the `format()` with `/` if needed. Also take a look at the [Carbon docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs) to see what other methods are available.

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '05-04-1972 19:03:11' for column 'from' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `discounts` (`name`, `from`, `to`, `status`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Ms. Cassandra Raynor, 05-04-1972 19:03:11, 19-08-2014 03:56:37, 0, 2022-01-27 00:24:07, 2022-01-27 00:24:07))

Comment: It's have an error. I think because I defined wrong value for from column for it

            $table->dateTime('from', $precision =0);

How can I fix this ?